# Helios voting system voting verification

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, voting

In the decryption step in [helios](https://documentation.heliosvoting.org/verification-specs/helios-v4), why do we need Chaum-Pedersen to prove that a certain plaintext $m$ corresponds to a given ciphertext $c$? 
Why can we just encrypt $m$ and see if it's equal to $c$?

Comment: How exactly you know the randomness r that was used for generating c?

Comment: Some plaintext can generate different ciphertexts. It is about IND-CPA?